# Saving file after removing json node

Tags: json, groovy

i was trying to remove json node from json file. For parsing ande getting not i used json slurper

```
File f=new File(fileLocation);
 def result = new JsonSlurper().parseText(f.text)
 Map jsonResult = (Map) result; 
 Map Bookmarkbar = (Map) jsonResult.get("roots").get("bookmark_bar");
List Children=(List) Bookmarkbar.get("children");
 println("no of elements "+Children.get(i).size());
 if("Google".equals(Children.get(i).get("name"))
{
 Children.remove(i);
 println(Children.get(i));
}
```

here it is removing ith node of children.But when i checked in the json file  i could see change is not happend ? println(Children.get(i)); is displaying next node after the removed one .and count also is decremented .so  how will i save the file after removing the child node ?

Answer (score 10):

You don't say what your JSON looks like, so I've had a guess...  I put:

```
{ "roots":{
    "bookmark_bar":{
      "children":[
        { "name":"Google", "url":"http://www.google.com" },
        { "name":"StackOverflow", "url":"http://stackoverflow.com" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

into `/tmp/test.json`

And then running this script:

```
import groovy.json.*

File jsonFile = new File( '/tmp/test.json' )

// Load the Json into a Map
Map result = new JsonSlurper().parseText( jsonFile.text )

// Set the children to every element whos name isn't Google
result.roots.bookmark_bar.children = result.roots.bookmark_bar.children.findAll {
  it.name != 'Google'
}

// Get the new JSON string
String newJson = new JsonBuilder( result ).toPrettyString()

// And write it out to the file again
jsonFile.withWriter( 'UTF-8' ) { it << newJson }
```

Changes the file contents to:

```
{
    "roots": {
        "bookmark_bar": {
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "StackOverflow",
                    "url": "http://stackoverflow.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: yes exactly the same but will it save back the file /tmp/test.json with update?

Comment: @Rajani Yes..  the last line `jsonFile.withWriter( 'UTF-8' ) { it << newJson }` saves it to the file...